# "along with the rest of us" at the end of a sentence

Tags: punctuation, commas

Considering this sentence:

*They will have to adapt to it along with the rest of us.*

... I feel like I want to insert a comma before "along" for emphasis. However, I think it's formally incorrect, but would be fine informally. My reasoning is that *along with the rest of us* is a dependent clause at the end of the sentence, and that doesn't require a comma.

Am I correct, or have I twisted myself in knots over it all?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "formally incorrect"; there's nothing wrong with the sentence, with or without the comma. There is an ambiguity -- either `They` will have to adapt to both `it` and to `the rest of us`, or `They` and `the rest of us` will have to adapt to `it`. The second is what's meant, obviously -- obviously to a human, that is; a computer will recognize both senses.

Comment: By "formally incorrect", I meant "according to generally accepted usage". I often get stymied by the various nuances of comma rules (for want of a better term), and this was one of those cases. I was sticking on the dependent clause bit, if it actually even is a dependent clause. I just did it again in the last sentence, in fact.

Comment: @JohnLawler I keep thinking of a “rescue reading” of that sentence as something Gomez Addams might say about how the new neighbors will have to get used to Cousin It and also to the rest of Gomez’s strange family. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main point is to communicate your intended meaning as unambiguously as possible. In this case, inserting the comma is what is needed to achieve that objective:

*They will have to adapt to it, along with the rest of us.*

The comma does not make it incorrect: there is no 'rule' that makes it impermissible to use a comma to mark off a dependent clause. In any case, the requirements of clarity trump all so-called 'rules'.

Comment: "In any case, the requirements of clarity trump all so-called 'rules'." Thanks, Erik. Always a good reminder.

Answer (score 0):

"Along with the rest of us" is not a dependent clause. To be a dependent clause it has to have a subject and a predicate. This is a prepositional phrase at the end of the sentence that doesn't require a comma.

Comment: All true, but the comma is not incorrect.