# A subordinate clause beginning with "if"

Tags: punctuation

Should this sentence have a comma: "It was dark, if you recall." 
It's a dependent clause so it should not need one, but it doesn't sound right without it.

Comment: The clause 'if you recall' here is a pragmatic marker soliciting confirmation (cf 'wasn't it?') or encouraging aquiescence (cf 'as I'm sure you'll agree'). It stands apart from the statement in the main clause. I'd certainly add the comma. The situation is different with say 'It was dark if clouds heralding one of the frequent storms came close'.

Comment: [temp comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/170576/along-with-the-rest-of-us-at-the-end-of-a-sentence?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

In a comment, Edwin Ashworth wrote:

> The clause 'if you recall' here is a pragmatic marker soliciting confirmation (cf 'wasn't it?') or encouraging aquiescence (cf 'as I'm sure you'll agree'). It stands apart from the statement in the main clause. I'd certainly add the comma. The situation is different with say 'It was dark if clouds heralding one of the frequent storms came close'.

Answer (score -1):

No, no comma is called for.

When a dependent "if" clause follows the main clause, no comma is required.  A comma is only required when the dependent "if" clause precedes the main clause.  You'll note in both of the following links, it explicity instructs not to use a comma when the dependent clause follows:

> ["Don’t use a comma if the if clause is at the end of the sentence."](https://www.ego4u.com/en/cram-up/writing/comma?10)

https://www.ego4u.com/en/cram-up/writing/comma?10

> ["However, don't put a comma after the main clause when a dependent
>   (subordinate) clause follows it."](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/607/2/)

https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/607/2/

Comment: If there is no ambiguity of meaning without comma, why not avoid it...